# python: one kernel density plot which includes multiple columns in a single dataframe

Tags: python, kernel-density

I need to make a single gaussian kernel density plot of a dataframe with multiple columns which includes all columns of the dataframe. Does anyone know how to do this?

So far I only found how to draw a gaussian kernel plot of a single column with seaborn. `ax = sns.kdeplot(df['shop1'])`
However, neither `ax = sns.kdeplot(df)`nor`ax = sns.kdeplot(df['shop1','shop2])` do not work.

Otherwise is there a workaround where I could transform the dataframe with shape `df.shape`(544, 33) to (17952, 2), by appending each columns to eachother?

The dataframe includes normalized prices for one product, whereas each column represents a different seller and the rows indicate date and time of the prices.

Answer (score 0):

I did find how to work around by transforming the dataframe's columns into one single column.

> `df.stack()`